# Finding out how many older siblings an individual has in a longitudinal database in excel

Tags: excel

My data looks like this:

- id  - - family#  - - Birthdate   - - collection_date
- 1      - - - 56    - - - -  2-Mar-86        - - - - -1997
- 1      - - - 56    - - - -  2-Mar-86        - - - - - 1998
- 2      - - - 56    - - - -  30-Aug-82       - - - - - 1997
- 2      - - - 56     - - - -  30-Aug-82       - - - - - 1998
- 3      - - - 48     - - - -  1-Sep-90        - - - - - 1997
- 3      - - - 48     - - - -  1-Sep-90        - - - - - 1998
- 4      - - - 48     - - - -  15-Oct-91       - - - - - 1997
- 4      - - - 48     - - - -  15-Oct-91       - - - - - 1998

The database is longitudinal.  The id number represents an individual while the family number represent genetic kinship.  What I would like to do is make a new row that calculate the number of older siblings each individual has.  So essentially what I would like to do is if x is the birthdate of the individual and y is the birthday of other individuals within the same family then for every later y add one and for any earlier y don't add anything.

Is there a way to do this and apply it to every individual?  My database is large.  It has about 30 individuals with 13 years of data for each.

Comment: Is the data sorted at all (it looks like it is in your example) or can it be sorted? What is the maximum number of records per family?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in columns A to D you could add this formula in E2 to get the required results

`=SUMPRODUCT(((B$2:B$10=B2)*(C$2:C$10<C2))/COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,A$2:A$10&""))`

You need such a formula to avoid double counting where individuals have more than one entry. It relies upon the ID in column A being numeric - if that isn't the case then I can adjust the formula to work.

Note: the formula is simply counting family members who are older - I don't see how you can guarantee that they are siblings, could they not be mothers, uncles or cousins etc.?

The formula can be slow if applied to a large number of rows, so if you have data sorted by family you can be creative in how it is applied, e.g. if maximum number of records per family is 200 you only need formulas that will look within a limited range, e.g. 200 rows in each direction

Comment: This helped out a lot.  The database is that of only children, so family number, in this case, indicates shared parents.  I have one more question, which I forgot to mention.  I have another parameter and that would be the sex of the child.  For example, if I wanted to find out how many older brothers or how many older sisters.  Each individual has either a 0 or a 1 for sex (female or male respectively).  Is there a way to add this parameter to the formula above?

Comment: I am also having a bit of a problem with the 200X200 limit.  My database has over 5000 rows of information (280+ individuals X 13 years of collection).  Is there anyway to apply this type of formula to a much larger database?  Also, is there a way to tease out how many older brothers vs. how many older sisters if I have a column with sex of the individual?

Answer (score 0):

use sumifs.

At the end of you database add a column of 1's. i.e., fill all the cells with the value 1, this is what we will add up to get the count of the siblings.

Now add the sumifs formal, like this

> =SUMIFS(Range_of_1's, Genetic_fam_col, Genetic_val_to_match, Birthdate_column, Birthdate_to_match*)

*to get the birthday bit to work you will need a cell that has something like >birthdate or something like this..., where birthdate is a date...

hopefully you get the idea